# How do I return $wpdb->get_results as json in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I created a custom table in wordpress called `custom_users` and I want to access the records via the API

**functions.php**

```
function get_wp_custom_users()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $custom_users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_custom_users");

    foreach ($custom_users as $custom_user)
    {
        echo $custom_user->first_name.' '.$custom_user->last_name;
    }
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function()
{
    register_rest_route( 'wpcustomusers/v1', '/users/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_wp_custom_users'
    ));
});
```

The API can be accessed via url `http://localhost/mywebsite/wp-json/wpcustomusers/v1/users`

Do you know how can I return the results inside the `for loop` as JSON from the API request?

I hope to see all the fields returned.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Replace the loop with `echo json_encode($custom_users);` …?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need of `foreach` loop, make changes as below.

```
function get_wp_custom_users(){
  global $wpdb;

  $custom_users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_custom_users");

  //change as below.
  echo json_encode($custom_users);
}
```

Comment: i tried return json_encode($custom_users); but I am seeing an empty array

Comment: you have to `echo` it, not return.

Comment: you are right. i had a typo in my table. it's working now

Comment: Or use the wordpress function wp_send_json();

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump` $custom_users to make sure $custom_users is not empty. Skip `for loop`. Replace **return** with **echo**.

```
echo json_encode($custom_users);
```